# Can't figure out how to set java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, opencv

I've looked at several other similar questions here, but none of them have been helping. I am able to run my program in eclipse, but once I try to export it as a jar, it can't find the opencv library:

```
C:\Users\Cory\Desktop>java -jar MazeBot.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java249 in
java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at MazeBot.main(MazeBot.java:38)
```

By looking at the responses for other questions, I tried setting my PATH variable to C:\OpenCV (I put a copy of opencv_java249.dll in there), which didn't work at all. Then, I tried adding `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\OpenCV")` as the first line of my code, but this also did nothing.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using: `java -jar MazeBot.jar -Ljava.library.path="C:\\OpenCV"`

This has cannot be in the application itself because you are importing OpenCV before the System.setProperty(...) line gets executed.